# Don't show the last screen briefly on resuming an app

Tags: android, onresume

I have built an app that shows an access code screen whenever the app is brought to the foreground.

What I've noticed on lower end devices is that there's a screenshot of the screen that is displayed prior to showing the access code screen.

How can I stop this previous screen from displaying prior to me showing the access code screen?

Comment: this needs more explanation. what is the "previous" screen ? is it from the previous activity ? than your activity is not started. if it is from an other app, than your app is not started. i am sure, i did understand your question.